# How to install pango for Python on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, cairo, pango

Since ReportLab does not support Python 3 I am now attempting to generate PDF with cairo, which works but lacks text-wrapping support. The next step seems to require pango and its Python-bindings, but I cannot find any information on how to install this for Windows.

Comment: My question is now over five years old and outdated -- Reportlab is available for Python 3 and probably has been for a while: https://pypi.org/project/reportlab/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Anaconda's conda package manager. But, what i found from the personal experiment that the pango works with python3 and cairo works with python2. and You my friend is stuck in middle.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install Pango on Windows is probably to install GTK, which bundles it.

You can find [Windows installers on GitHub](https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer/releases).

This is [the method recommended by WeasyPrint](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/weasyprint/stable/first_steps.html#windows) (another PDF library for Python).

Answer (score -2):

For Mac you can use Brew to install Pango:

`brew install pango`